# Intercept requests going from the sidebar panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Firefox allows us to apply filters like `tabId`, `urls` to requests before intercepting them using [webRequest.RequestFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/RequestFilter)

So far so good. The problem is this code

```
browser.sidebarAction.setPanel({
    panel: 'https://google.com'
});
```

Here we are requesting a web page that will be loaded into the sidebar (**I want to intercept that request only**)

As you can see it seems that there's no way to only filter `sidebars`' requests since even `tabId` will return the same id as the "parent" tab

Is it really possible to intercept requests going from the sidebar panel only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can filter requests that aren't related to a tab by setting `tabId` to -1

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  listener,
  {
      urls: ["<all_urls>"],
      tabId: -1
  },
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

This now matches our sidebar's requests